# Save 'Username' as Filename

Tags: php, aurigma

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I'm using Image Uploader from Aurigma, and to save the uploaded images, I've put this script together.

```
<?php

//This variable specifies relative path to the folder, where the gallery with uploaded files is located.
//Do not forget about the slash in the end of the folder name.
$galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/';

require_once 'Includes/gallery_helper.php';

require_once 'ImageUploaderPHP/UploadHandler.class.php';

/**
 * FileUploaded callback function
 * @param $uploadedFile UploadedFile
 */
function onFileUploaded($uploadedFile) {

  $packageFields = $uploadedFile->getPackage()->getPackageFields();
  $userid = $packageFields["userid"];
  $locationid= $packageFields["locationid"];

  global $galleryPath;

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $absThumbnailsPath = $absGalleryPath . 'Thumbnails' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

  if ($uploadedFile->getPackage()->getPackageIndex() == 0 && $uploadedFile->getIndex() == 0) {
    initGallery($absGalleryPath, $absThumbnailsPath, FALSE);
  }

  $dirName = $_POST['folder'];
  $dirName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $dirName);
  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath . $dirName)) {
    mkdir($absGalleryPath . $dirName, 0777);
  }

  $path = rtrim($dirName, '/\\') . '/';

  $originalFileName = $uploadedFile->getSourceName();

  $files = $uploadedFile->getConvertedFiles();

  // save converter 1

  $sourceFileName = getSafeFileName($absGalleryPath, $originalFileName);
  $sourceFile = $files[0];
  /* @var $sourceFile ConvertedFile */
  if ($sourceFile) {
    $sourceFile->moveTo($absGalleryPath . $sourceFileName);
  }

  // save converter 2   

  $thumbnailFileName = getSafeFileName($absThumbnailsPath, $originalFileName);
  $thumbnailFile = $files[1];
  /* @var $thumbnailFile ConvertedFile */
  if ($thumbnailFile) {
    $thumbnailFile->moveTo($absThumbnailsPath . $thumbnailFileName);
  }

  //Load XML file which will keep information about files (image dimensions, description, etc).
  //XML is used solely for brevity. In real-life application most likely you will use database instead.
  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');

  //Save file info.
  $xmlFile = $descriptions->createElement('file');
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('name', $_POST['folder'] . '/' . $originalFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('source', $sourceFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('size', $uploadedFile->getSourceSize());
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('originalname', $originalFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('thumbnail', $thumbnailFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('description', $uploadedFile->getDescription());
  //Add additional fields
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('userid', $userid);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('locationid', $locationid);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('folder', $dirName);
  $descriptions->documentElement->appendChild($xmlFile);
  $descriptions->save($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');
}

$uh = new UploadHandler();
$uh->setFileUploadedCallback('onFileUploaded');
$uh->processRequest();
?>
```

What I'd like to do is replace the `files` element of the filename and replace it with the `username`, so each saved folder and associated files can be indentified to each user.

I've added a username text field to the form which this script saves from

I think I'm right in saying that this is line that needs to change `$descriptions->save($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');`.

So amongst many attempts I've tried changing this to `$descriptions->save($absGalleryPath . '$username.xml`, `$descriptions->save($absGalleryPath . $username '.xml`, but none of these have worked, so I'm not quite sure what I need to change.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps have a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'$username.xml' will be interpreted as $username.xml, you need to use "$username.xml".  Single quotes "disable" the variable use inside strings.

What you are tryiing can be a bad idea, as you are making so a username can't contain 'special characters' like "/". Perhaps is not a problem if you aready have a rule that stop "/" being part of a username.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to help me out. Kind regards.